# Data not being populated in wso2is-analytics-5.8.0 dashboard that is integrated with wso2is-km-5.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is-km-5.9.0 for serving our application authentication and SSO needs and we have coupled wso2is-analytics-5.8.0 with our Identity Server. I have followed the steps mentioned in the offical documentation i.e setting Analytics in api-manager.xml to True and enabling the eventpublishers but I'm unable to see any data in Analytics dashboard. Please refer the error logs for the same attached.
Why is the data not being populated in WSO2 analytics dashboard??
[Analytics error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uMhW.png)
[Identity Server error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srgzz.png)

Comment: have you enabled email as user name?

Answer (score 0):

With the new config model introduction, you should not edit the api-manager.xml file. It should be done via deployement.toml file.

Moreover you have to enable event listeners and publishes in deployment.toml file. This will enable publishing data to the analytics. You should refer the documentation in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-identity-analytics/ because IS  and IS-KM is more similar, difference is having an apim-manger.xml file.

```
[[event_listener]]
id = "authn_data_publisher_proxy"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityMessageHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.data.publisher.application.authentication.AuthnDataPublisherProxy" 
order = 11 

[identity_mgt.analytics_login_data_publisher]
enable=true

[identity_mgt.analytics_session_data_publisher] 
enable=true
```